# SharePoint custom master page deployed via WSP

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I made a solution to deploy a custom master page (a WSP file).
After I activated the solution, I fired up SPD to make a new page based on the custom master page.
My elements.xml file has:

```
<Module Name="AddCustomMasterBMW1" Url="_catalogs/MasterPage">
<File Url="customWSPTest1.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
  <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_masterpage_name;"></Property>
</File>
```

My issue is how do I surf to this custom master page in SPD to select the master page to use?
The custom master page is in the DB, i assume, so how do I tell SPD to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SPD, navigate to _catalogs/masterpage. Right click on the customWSPTest1.master and select Set as Custom Master Page. That said, I actually find it easier to use the browser. Go to Site Settings, click Master page under Look and Feel, and change the Site Master Page to customWSPTest1.master.

Comment: thanks, but I want to make a new page, using the custom master as the master, the SPD diaglog that comes up when I choose to "make a page based on a master page" will not let me choose my new custom master page. maybe I am not clear enough what I want to do?

Comment: You can't "make" a page from a master page in SharePoint. You make a page from either a Publishing Page Layout (for publishing sites) or one of the other basic/webpart page templates for other sites. You master page is there to enforce a consistent look and feel for all your pages in your site.

Comment: @bmw0128 - I think I see what you're saying and I don't think that's a property that can be set through the provisioning XML. Instead, it's actually in the .aspx file. If you take a look at the MasterPageFile attribute of the Page directive, it will most likely say "~masterurl/custom.master", which is a SharePoint variable that points to the Custom Master Page I described above. To point any pages that use that .aspx file to your master page, you can change the setting to be MasterPageFile="~sitecollection/_catalogs/MasterPage/customWSPTest1.master"